# parameters for local and global costmaps for move_base package

Tags: navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have completed the mapping with my laser sensors and now want to make a path planning for my robot. The map I have made is static (no dynamic objects, just for the initial testing) and here are my map parameters:

```
 resolution: 0.050000
 origin: [-100.000000, -100.000000, 0.000000]
 negate: 0
 occupied_thresh: 0.65
 free_thresh: 0.196
```

The map is 4000x4000 px and with resolution of 0.05 I get 200x200 meters size.

Now, in order for the path planning, I need a local and global costmap params, and here I need your help. Here are my local costmap params:

```
local_costmap:
  update_frequency: 5
  publish_frequency: 5
  transform_tolerance: 0.25 # 0.25 seconds of latency, if greater than this, planner will stop
  static_map: true
  rolling_window: true # Follow robot while navigating
  width: 3
  height: 3
  origin_x: -1.5
  origin_y: -1.5
  resolution: 0.05
  inflation_radius: 0.2
```

And my global params:

```
global_costmap:
  update_frequency: 5
  publish_frequency: 5
  transform_tolerance: 0.25 # 0.25 seconds of latency, if greater than this, planner will stop
  static_map: true
  rolling_window: true # Follow robot while navigating
  width: 200
  height: 200
  origin_x: -100
  origin_y: -100
  resolution: 0.05
  inflation_radius: 0.2
```

**Did I choose ok values for my params? I have included the params of my map into global costmap and chose my own smaller values for my local_costmap
Also, I will not need any sensor readings as the map is static, can I just ignore the cosmtap_common_params, which I have defined like this but want to exclude when running a path planing using move_base package?**

```
obstacle_range: 6.0
raytrace_range: 8.5
footprint: [[0.12, 0.14], [0.12, -0.14], [-0.12, -0.14], [-0.12, 0.14]]
map_topic: /map
subscribe_to_updates: true
observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: laser_frame, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
global_frame: map
robot_base_frame: base_link
always_send_full_costmap: true
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305977/parameters-for-local-and-global-costmaps-for-move_base-package/) by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 361 on 2018-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the `inflation_radius` and `cost_saling_factor` parameters should go under the `inflater_layer` in both global and local costmap params files like this:

```
  inflater_layer:
    inflation_radius: 0.2
    cost_scaling_factor: 1.0
```

You should have this in each global and local costmap param files only if you want different inflation for them.

You should still use the `cosmtap_common_params` file since it is there that you usually put the frame, footprint and plugins params. For example in your `cosmtap_common_params` you should have something like this:

```
global_frame: map
robot_base_frame: base_link

footprint: [[0.12, 0.14], [0.12, -0.14], [-0.12, -0.14], [-0.12, 0.14]]
footprint_padding: 0.03

plugins:
- {name: static_layer, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
# - {name: obstacles_layer, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
- {name: inflater_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

static_layer:
  map_topic: /map
  subscribe_to_updates: true

# obstacles_layer:
#   observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
#   laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: laser_frame, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true,  obstacle_range: 6.0, raytrace_range: 8.5}

inflater_layer:
  inflation_radius: 0.2
  cost_scaling_factor: 1.0
```

If you want to have the same inflation for both global and local costmap then you put the params in the common_costmap file like it is shown above.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2018-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on 2018-10-17**:
Thank you for the answer. Am I correct with the global costmap parameters to follow my map yaml parameters and local one I can choose which suits me best?

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-10-17**:
I dont know your full setup.  I updated the answer with all of the parameters that should be in your common_costmap file with regards to your global and local files. For reference you can always check out the [husky](https://github.com/husky/husky/tree/kinetic-devel/husky_navigation) configuration.

**Comment by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on 2018-10-17**:
@pavel92 Thank you, it worked good but sometimes the robot does not go to the desired destination and stops. The terminal states this warning:

```
[ WARN] [1539771436.939121236, 41.659000000]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 5.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.2290 seconds
```

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-10-17**:
Im glad it helped. You can mark the answer as correct now as it solved your initial problem.
As for the new warning check [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/195523/warning-map-update-loop-missed-its-desired-rate-keeps-on-comming/) question. It comes down to tuning the update parameters.